Python is interpreting \n as 0xd0 when reading as bytes
Newline is getting interpreted as Ð (0xd0) instead of (0x0a) and I genuinely don't have any idea on how to fix this. I don't know where to begin either.
When trying to use this code, it reads 0x0a as 0xd0.
with open(path, "rb") as root:
    b_arr = root.read() + b" "
    print("Processing...")
    buffer = ""
    b_arr_wizard = ""
    chars = ""
    for i in range(len(b_arr)):
        if i % 16 == 0 or i == len(b_arr)-1:

            print(len(buffer))
            buffer += " "*((16*3)-len(buffer))
            buffer += "| "
            for _ in buffer.split():
                if _ == "|":
                    continue

                #print(_)
                if int(_, base=16) >= 32:
                    buffer += chr(int(_, base=16))
                    chars += chr(int(_, base=16))
                else:
                    buffer += "."
                    chars += chr(int(_, base=16))
            b_arr_wizard += buffer + "\n"
            buffer = ""

        buffer += str(hex(b_arr[i])[2:])+ "0"*(2-len(str(hex(b_arr[i])[2:]))) + " "

used on the file:
abc
def

returns:
61 62 63 d0 a0 64 65 66                         | abcÐ def

it reads both 0xd0 (a carriage return) and 0xa0 (a line feed), not instead of

@OneCricketeer I see now, so python's chr() function is using the extended ascii codes too? which just so happens to have 0xd0 as Ð instead of \r?

Python chr() and ord() uses Unicode code points. Your terminal settings may print something else

Why not just print(b_arr.hex(' '))?

It is important t understand that '\n' is just a shortcut used in many programming languages to allow to embed what would otherwise be an unprintable character.  The Python string "\n" contains one character, and it is not a backslash.  It is the character with ASCII value 10 decimal, or 0x0a.  Similarly, the string "\r" is also one character, with ASCII value 13 decimal, or 0x0d.

Actually your code returns None because you don't have a return statement.  Please post actual working code.

@MarkRansom (sorry for the late), but this isnt in a function. I dont know where you got it from.

The question says "returns" even though there's no return or print shown.  I had to assume because you weren't clear.

@MarkRansom oh yeah, when i said "returns", i meant when it write to a file/stdout, it shows the "returns" section

You're putting the "0" in the wrong position, carriage return is 0x0D and new line is 0x0a not 0xd0 and 0xa0 respectively.
The zero should be leading not trailing
buffer += "0"*(2-len(str(hex(b_arr[i])[2:]))) + str(hex(b_arr[i])[2:])+ " "


Also, the file comes from a Windows machine, where newlines are usually \r\n or 0x0d 0x0a in hex.

Why not just use f"{b_arr[i]:02x} "?

@MatBailie I don't really know python that well, I was just looking at the logic.

It's just standard string interpolation formatting. Format the variable as hex, with left padding 2, using zeros.

I couldn't reproduce your output when I ran your code.
It's not clear what your end goal of this code is, but it does not seem to be leveraging the full power of Python to display the expected output text.
An alternative strategy would be to read the file as a binary file in 16 byte chunks, then print the raw hex values and printable ASCII for each chunk.
A possible way of doing that would be:
path = "junk.txt"
buffer_size = 16
display_width = (buffer_size * 2) + buffer_size

with open(path, mode="rb") as f:
    while chunk := f.read(buffer_size):
        bin_value = " ".join([f"{x:02X}" for x in chunk])
        printable = "".join(
            [x if x.isprintable() else "\ufffd" for x in chunk.decode("ascii")]
        )

        print(f"{bin_value:<{display_width}} | {printable}")

Which for your example file would give:
61 62 63 0D 0A 64 65 66                          | abc��def

which highlights your code is incorrectly outputting D0 and A0 rather than 0D and 0A.
Or for a slightly bigger file would give:
61 62 63 0D 0A 64 65 66 0D 0A 54 68 65 20 71 75  | abc��def��The qu
69 63 6B 20 62 72 6F 77 6E 20 66 6F 78 20 6A 75  | ick brown fox ju
6D 70 65 64 20 6F 76 65 72 20 74 68 65 20 6C 61  | mped over the la
7A 79 20 63 6F 77 2E 0D 0A                       | zy cow.��


NOTE: I've chosen to replace any unprintable characters with � to make it clear that these are not printable values. e.g. CR and LF characters.

